# Plotting the same line with 2 different line types on ggolot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I would like to use 2 line types for the 2 parts of the line: for example, dashed line from Dark to Dim, solid line from Dim to Ambient. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks a lot!

Here is my current code:

```
df <- ggplot(aes(y=Expression, x=Treatment, group=FS_Gene)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color=AM_vs_CM_Sig))
```

Here is my example data from `dput`:

```r
structure(list(query = c("GS1", "GS1", "GS1", "GS1", "GS1", "GS1", 
"GS1"), FS_Gene = c("FS_gene_30096", "FS_gene_30096", "FS_gene_30096", 
"FS_gene_4414", "FS_gene_4414", "FS_gene_4414", "FS_gene_58593"
), AM_vs_BM_Sig = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("N", 
"Y"), class = "factor"), AM_vs_CM_Sig = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), BM_vs_CM_Sig = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
    Treatment = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("Dark", 
    "Dim", "Ambient"), class = "factor"), Tissue = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Foot", "Mantle"), class = "factor"), 
    Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = "FS", class = "factor"), 
    Expression = c(136.7586, 197.294625, 165.17225, 4.5402, 6.27425, 
    4.406375, 2.255375)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), na.action = structure(c(`190` = 190L, `191` = 191L, 
`192` = 192L, `193` = 193L, `194` = 194L, `195` = 195L, `211` = 211L, 
`212` = 212L, `213` = 213L, `214` = 214L, `215` = 215L, `216` = 216L, 
`220` = 220L, `221` = 221L, `222` = 222L, `238` = 238L, `239` = 239L, 
`240` = 240L, `244` = 244L, `245` = 245L, `246` = 246L, `277` = 277L, 
`278` = 278L, `279` = 279L, `322` = 322L, `323` = 323L, `324` = 324L, 
`367` = 367L, `368` = 368L, `369` = 369L, `376` = 376L, `377` = 377L, 
`378` = 378L, `490` = 490L, `491` = 491L, `492` = 492L, `496` = 496L, 
`497` = 497L, `498` = 498L, `526` = 526L, `527` = 527L, `528` = 528L, 
`532` = 532L, `533` = 533L, `534` = 534L), class = "omit"))
```

[My current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxjGB.png)

Comment: Hi! Can you send some lines of your dataframe, so we can try to do it?

Comment: If you run `dput(data.frame(Expression, Treatment, FS_Gene, AM_vs_CS_Sig))`, you can paste the output into the body of your question to make it easy for people to try out solutions on your data.

Comment: `geom_segment` and `ggforce::geom_link`/`ggforce::geom_link2` are my go-to ways of making the aesthetics vary along the length of a line series.

Comment: I just added it! The idea is to show line plots from CM - BM - AM, if CM vs BM  or AM vs CM is significant, I wants to use solid lines for that part, if not, dashed lines.  I would like to use red to represent AM-CM significant, otherwise grey. Thank you so much and look forward to hearing back!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?
You have to create columns `xend` and `yend` from the x axis variable.

```r
# test data
df1 <- iris[c(1, 51, 101), 3:5]
names(df1) <- c("N", "Y", "x")
df1
#>       N   Y          x
#> 1   1.4 0.2     setosa
#> 51  4.7 1.4 versicolor
#> 101 6.0 2.5  virginica

suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(ggplot2)
  library(tidyr)
  library(dplyr)
})

df1 %>%
  pivot_longer(-x) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(xend = lead(x),
         yend = lead(value),
         linetype = factor(row_number())) %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = value, color = name)) +
  geom_segment(aes(xend = xend, yend = yend, linetype = linetype))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I just added an example of my dataset. Would you mind trying with my data? It seems that mine is more complicated. Thanks a lot!